# How to aggregate values in C++ using keys?

Tags: c++, hash, aggregation

In C++ how can I aggregate values for a struct based on three keys?

In Perl I would do this using a hash of hashes (e.g. something like $hash{$key1}{$key2}{$key3}{'call_duration'} += 25);

As I'm a complete newbie to C++ could you please suggest a suitable approach?

I've had a look at topics on SO discussing nested hash equivalents in C++ using std::map, however it states that this is slow performance-wise and as I need to process records for a telecom operator, performance is critical.

It's not necessary that I follow an approach that uses the template library or anything that should resemble Perl in syntax and mindset, but if you have had to do something similar, could you please share a fast and suitable way to implement it?

I'm mostly limited to the C++ 98 standard (the technical lead has allowed the use of newer features provided that they are supported by the compiler and they are of critical benefit).

Apologies if the description is muddled and thanks in advance!

edit: The compiler version is GCC 4.1.2, importing tr1/functional as a library isn't frowned upon by it.

edit: Thanks very much to everyone that joined, in particular to Bartek and Rost for putting up with my stupid questions. I decided to choose Rost's answer as it's what I was actually able to get to work! :)

Comment: A map with a triple as the key sounds reasonable.

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you are trying to do? It would also help to understand what type the keys are. (If you want to use search engines, search for "unordered map".)

Comment: either `std::map<std::tuple<>, TValue>`, `std::map<TStructOfThreeKeys, TValue>` or `boost::multi_index`

Comment: Can you use the TR1 libraries?

Comment: If you're looking for hashmaps in C++, look here : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map if you are using a compiler that supports C++11.

Comment: @Cubic many compilers already implemented `hash_map` as unofficial extension

Comment: Thanks very much for the comments.

I need to aggregate call records by time slot, record type and source of the record (these are my keys). 
So for every timeslot encountered, for every source id in that timeslot and for every record type that has the same source id, I need to aggregate the call duration and one other float field. These would then be forwarded to an audit database.

A Perl hash as a concept seems fairly suitable, however obviously I need to do it in C++ :)

Comment: @KerrekSB
It seems that the compiler does accept a TR1 library, looking at Wiki it states that TR1 supports hash tables, is this what you have in mind? :)

Comment: @Nobilis You should add the TR1 part (or even the particular compiler) to your question by editing it.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz
Fair observation, will do. However, I seem to be having problems with unordered_map, as even after adding the library the compiler refuses to recognise std::unordered_map.

Comment: hmm, I followed the wikipedia example on TR1 and included tr1/functional which the compiler was okay with, however after adding tr1 or unordered_map it failed to compile. Nevermind, I'll try the examples below, seeing as it'll probably be best if I can stick to the standard features.

Comment: are you sure you have correct includes and namespaces?

Comment: Yeah, <tr1/functional> was okay, <tr> wasn't, nor was <unordered_map> :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common `std::map` shall be suitable, its performance is usually not a problem for most cases. Hash provides constant time access to elements, tree-based map provides logarithmic time, but in reality constant time maybe greater than logarithmic - it depends on specific implementation and specific data. In case when you fill container once and then only update data without key changing/inserting/deleting you could use sorted `std::vector` or `Loki::AssocVector`.

You shall first try `std::map` (or `std::set` if the key is actully part of data) and only then make decision is it too slow for you or not. Example:

```
// Composite key definition
struct CompositeKey
{
   int key1;
   std::string key2;
   AnotherType key3;

   CompositeKey(int i_key1, const std::string& i_key2, AnotherType i_key3):
      key1(i_key1), key2(i_key2), key3(i_key3)
   {}

   bool operator < (const CompositeKey& i_rhs) const
   {
      // You must define your own less operator for ordering keys
   }
};

// Usage
std::map<CompositeKey, Data> aggrData;

aggrData[CompositeKey(0, "KeyString", AnotherType())] = Data();

if(aggrData.find(CompositeKey(0, "KeyString", AnotherType())) != aggrData.end())
{
   // Process found data
}
```

For further performance research you could try:

- [`hash_map`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html)/[`hash_set`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_set.html) (named [`stdex::hash_map`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d462wfh%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in MSVC++ and `__gnu_cxx::hash_map` in GCC)
- [`boost::unordered_map`/`boost::unordered_set`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/unordered/)
- [`Loki::AssocVector`](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00025.html)
- [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)/[`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) - **for C++11 only**

All these containers have similar interface so it will not be difficult to encapsulate it and easily switch implementation if required.

Comment: There is no such thing as `std::hash_map`.

Comment: @DeadMG You right, fixed. As I remember it was in `std` in earlier GCC versions.

Comment: Sorry Rost, could you please help me with the definition of Data()? I created a struct named 'Data' that is initialised in a similar way to the CompositeKey, but whenever i pass it as Data(3, 3.4f), the compiler compains about no matching function for call Data::Data().
I added a comparison operator to Key and a constructor to Data, so not sure what the problem is :( Thanks.

Comment: @Nobilis Looks like you missed default ctor for `Data` (with no params or with all params with default values), its required to use `map::operator[]`

Comment: Alright, I will add that, thanks very much.
Also with regards to the comparison operator, I only compare the first key (i.e. something like `return this->timeSlot < i_rhs.timeSlot;`), would this be sufficient or should I add some sort of comparison for the other keys? And could you help me with that as well please :)

Comment: @Nobilis No, this is NOT sufficient, otherwise why do you need second and third keys? :-) You could drop them in this case. You need to compare them too.

Comment: @Rost
Yeah I thought it can't be all so I redefined the '<'operator as `return ( (this->timeSlot < comp.timeSlot) && (this->sourceID < comp.sourceID) && (this->recType < comp.recType) );`. And I initialise the map as: `std::map<Key, Data> myMap;` and then `myMap[Key("a", "b", "c")] = Data(3, 4.4f);`
However when running the app I get  `symbol lookup error: ~/app_flt_tsa.so undefined symbol: _ZN4DataC1Ev`. My keys are strings, so this can't be the problem. I suspect my comparison operator implementation is dodgy. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: @Nobilis When running? Or actually when compiling/linking? Looks like linker could not find Data() parameters ctor definition. Where it's defined/declared?

Comment: Actually, nevermind that I'll try using a <Key, int> array, if this is not straightforward to figure out.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, this is when I'm running the app, it compiles just fine. Which is the odd bit, when I use the `<Key, int>` combination it runs without any problems, but if I pass `Data(3, 3.4f)` to `<Key, Data>`, it will compile and everything, but will give me the above error.

Comment: I defined it like that `struct Data { int count; float weight; Data(); Data (int key1, float key2) : count(key1), weight(key2) {} };`

Comment: @Nobilis Aaah, that is the problem. You just declared `Data()`, but not defined it. Change `Data();` to `Data(): count(0), weight(0) {}` and it shall work.

Comment: Sorted it out, turns out the library I was using had been changed in the meantime hence all those weird errors, all's fine now, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution is to use struct aggregating the 3 keys, and use it as key.

```
struct Key
{
    Type1 Key1;
    Type2 Key2;
    Type3 Key3;

    // I forgot about the comparator - you have to provide it explicitly
};
```

Because you are somewhat limited with language, check if your compiler supports `std::hash_map`:

```
std::hash_map<Key, TValue> Data;
```

If not, you could always use `boost::unordered_map`.

If someone else stumbles on the same problem, the "proper solution", however, is this:

```
std::unordered_map<std::tuple<Type1, Type2, Type3>, TValue>;
```

EDIT: Sample usage

```
struct Key
{
    int Int;
    float Float;
    string String;
    // add ctor and operator<
};

std::hash_map<Key, int> Data;

Data[Key(5, 3.5f, "x")] = 10;
```

Comment: boost::multi_index provides multiple views on a container, not multiple dimensions or hash tables (or I might be misunderstanding your answer).

Comment: Yeah, after a bit of thinking, your comment makes sense. The object actually has **one** key - made from 3 sub-keys. So it's not exactly **multi**-index

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz
Thank you for your answer, I did have something like that in mind, however wouldn't that mean that performance would be slower?
As I imagine if you have them nested, once you found your first key, you need to search within that key only etc.

If I'm searching for the whole string (key1+key2+key3) wouldn't that mean that in the worst case scenario I would have to iterate through the whole list? As the incoming records won't be ordered, putting them in ordered order would probably incur some performance penalty.

Please correct me if I've misunderstood you.

Comment: @Nobilis - `std::(hash_)map` uses a tree at it's internal representation, so searh is done in `O(log n)`. Besides, if the key is hashed, every query hashes the incoming key, and then compares it with existing ones. It doesn't matter if the key has 3, 5 or 1000 elements. So *once you found your first key, you need to search within that key only etc* - is wrong. There's actually only **one** key, as I wrote earlier.

Comment: @Nobilis In most cases hash containers don't perform a search for key value. They calculate item position by hash function. It takes item key and returns item position in container. So it's time is constant and item could be accessed directly without any iterations. The problem arises when there are _collisions_ - when hash function produces the same position for different keys. So in _very worst case_ yes, it could be O(n) ("iterate through whole list"). Tree-based maps have always O(log n) complexity and never iterate through whole tree.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz
Could you please show me sample usage so I can get an idea of how it works? For example if I had as stated 3 keys and two fields to aggregate (with the option to add more). 
Because I'm not too sure how the fields that need aggregating relate to the struct itself. Would I have a <Key, Value> combination for each field?
Thanks.

Comment: No such thing as `std::hash_map`, only `unordered_map` and `map`.